# Add id from element inside already serialized form jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a dynamic list which can be ordered, the `id` of these elements changes accordingly.

My problem: I serialize the entire form and send it through ajax to a PHP script, but the `id` is not sent with that.

My array now looks like this for example:

```
Array
(
    [title] => lijsttitle
    [Category 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
        )

    [Category 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
        )

    [Category 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
        )

    [Category 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
        )

)
```

My HTML form which when posted generates above array looks like this:

```
<form id="lijstform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="lijstnaamtitle">Lijst naam</label>
            <input class="form-control name_list catinput lijsttitle" type="text" name="lijsttitle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamic_field" class="ui-sortable">
        <div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="1">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput">
                <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="2">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="2. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="3">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="3. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="4">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="4. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see every sortable row has an id: `<div class="row sortwrap" id="4">`

I would like that id inside my array for every category so I can update my database and later display the saved list in its correct order.

I've tried the following:

```
$( ".lijstbutton" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  url = 'includes/createlist.php';

  $lijst = $( '#lijstform' ).serializeArray();
  $idorder = $('.sortwrap').attr('id');

  var posting = $.post(url, {
    lijst: $lijst,
    idorder: $idorder
  });

    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".lijstresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
   });
  });
```

But when posted this is what I see in my network tab:

```
lijst[0][name]: lijsttitle
lijst[0][value]: List name
lijst[1][name]: category[]
lijst[1][value]: Category 1
lijst[2][name]: question[]
lijst[2][value]: Question 1
lijst[3][name]: category[]
lijst[3][value]: Category 2
lijst[4][name]: question[]
lijst[4][value]: Question 1
lijst[5][name]: category[]
lijst[5][value]: Category 3
lijst[6][name]: question[]
lijst[6][value]: Question 1
lijst[7][name]: category[]
lijst[7][value]: Category 4
lijst[8][name]: question[]
lijst[8][value]: Question 1
idorder: 1
```

Only the first one is posted.

This is how I generate the array in my PHP script:

```
$arr = $_POST['lijst'];

$store = [];

// pull off first arr element
$title = array_shift($arr);
// save title to store
$store['title'] = $title['name'];

$currCat = '';
foreach($arr as $a) {
  $val = $a['value'];
  // handle category
  if($a['name'] == 'category[]') {
    // save cat name
    $currCat = $val;
    // init questions array
    $store[$currCat] = [];
  }
  else {
    // add question to question array
    $store[$currCat][] = $val;
  }
}
```

Not sure what the best method is to add the order id to my array and how to do it.

Maybe add the `id` to every key after a barely used character? Something like [Category 1|1] and then explode on |

Comment: add `<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="id-here" />` in every row that needs an id

Comment: lookup `each` in the [jQuery Manual](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy approach will be to create `hidden` input under each `row sortwrap` which will get posted to when form is submitted.

```
<div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="1">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput">
        <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
        <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                    <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1" /> <!-- POST ID in Hidden input -->
</div>
```

Similarly, do it under all sortwrap container.

Another approach using your current flow is to use jQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function to retrieve all IDs.

Change

```
$idorder = $('.sortwrap').attr('id');
```

To

```
$idorder = $('.sortwrap').map(function() {
               return $(this).attr("id");
           }).get();
```